# Error importing tag from pattern3.en

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, virtualenv

I have installed  `pattern3` with `pip` in a `conda` virtual environment.  I am working in `Windows 8.1  64-bit` .When I try to execute

`from pattern3.en import tag`

I have the following errror:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_pattern.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pattern3.en import tag
  File "C:\Users\Rodolfo\Anaconda3\envs\flasky\lib\site-packages\pattern3\text\en\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pattern3.text import (
  File "C:\Users\Rodolfo\Anaconda3\envs\flasky\lib\site-packages\pattern3\text\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pattern3.text.tree import Tree, Text, Sentence, Slice, Chunk, PNPChunk, Chink, Word, table
  File "C:\Users\Rodolfo\Anaconda3\envs\flasky\lib\site-packages\pattern3\text\tree.py", line 37
    except:
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Any idea  or help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

I solved the issue. 
I received a message from *Markus Beuckelmann*  (github) :
 "...you are using the deprecated **pattern3** repository which contains a completely different code base that is not maintained anymore. There is a development branch here on clips/pattern with Python 3 support. You can clone it, git clone -b development https://github.com/clips/pattern and install with pip or conda....." 
However, I had many problems after cloning the repository and running `python setup.py install` 
Finally, I was able to install **pattern** using:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/your_user_id/pattern.git@development
```

Where `your_user_id` is your *github user id* which is inserted automatically when the repository path is copied to the clipboard.

Comment: I am getting Command "git clone -q https://github.com/your_user_id/pattern.git /tmp/pip-req-build-u6i00mum" failed with error code 128 in None
 error with the above command. I have added with my username, it asked me for my github login then shows this error.

Comment: try `pip install https://github.com/your_user_id/pattern/tarball/development`

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers solved my problem. At least not for the `pattern3` module which is available on PyPI through pip. 
I solved this by entering to the problematic file `(C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pattern3\text\tree.py)` and fixing the problem myself:

```py
from itertools import chain  # 34
try:                         # 35
    None                     # ===> THIS IS THE LINE I ADDED! <===
except:                      # 37
    izip = zip  # Python 3
```

Obviously, this is not a suitable answer for production environments. 
Alternatively, clone the current pattern repository on your computer and install it:

```sh
git clone -b development https://github.com/clips/pattern
cd pattern
python setup.py install
```

Then you must import `pattern` instead of `pattern3`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still have issue, you can run the command

```
sed -i '36s/.*/    pass/' /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pattern3/text/tree.py
```

I was using a dockerfile for the project so did the same.